# Where is the contact page?

Tags: cms, magento-1.9.2.1

We have a CMS page with URL key 'contact_btl'. However, the page URL in question is /contacts, and the content differs completely. The live page content consists of a map (which is a CMS block that leaves blank space when disabled) and a contact form (template part). Catalog > URL Rewrite Management does not appear to contain anything to do with it either.

So I guess my question is where might it be and/or how might I track it down?

Comment: please specific magento version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Magento 1.9.x.x,  you have at least two options:

1) Update the default `contacts.phtml` file located at `\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\contacts\form.phtml` (if you have a custom theme, use that directory - or copy this file to your custom theme in the same directory as to not override the default)

From there, you can use this file and basic `form` structure to change the fields that are available.

You can check which `.phtml` file is loading by using the `template path hints` option in your `System > Configuration > (change to store view instead of global) > Advanced > Developer > (include your IP in the field at top) > set Template Path Hints to YES > Save Config` - then reload your `/contacts` URL and you should see a path to which file is being loaded.

[image: contacts URL with Template Path Hints enabled]

2) Use [MageMe's WebForms extension](http://mageme.com/magento-extensions/magento-custom-form-builder-extension-webforms-professional-edition.html) which contains a better GUI based form builder that allows you to override the default `contacts` page.

There are other "contact form" extensions that alter how this page looks, but in my experience, webforms has been a lifesaver - and has utility beyond just the `contacts` page

Comment: Thanks SJ, but how there is supposed to be a contacts.phtml at form.phtml? Anyway no matter how it is that the URL is set for that page, all its content is indeed contained in the form.phtml which you speak of that we do have in our theme. I can't believe I didn't check it out to begin with, I must have just ASSumed terribly. Problem is my changes to the file are having no effect on the page. Oh well.

Comment: You can double check which `.phtml` file is loading by using the `load template hints` option in your `System > Configuration > (change to store view instead of global) > Advanced > Developer > (include your IP in the field at top) > set Template Path Hints to YES` - then reload your `/contacts` URL and you should see a path to which file is being loaded. I've added this and a photo to the answer.